# How to map the message to the vector of weight t in Niederreiter cryptosystem?

Tags: code-based-cryptography

In Niederreiter cryptosystem, we require the message to be a vector of weight $t$ in $F_q^n$ in encryption, assume $t$ is the error-correction ability of the code. But what is the mapping? One possible way is mapping the message of length $k$ to a codeword of a constant weight $t$ linear code, e.g., $[n,k]_q$ code. In this way, the message space is $q^k$. Is there other better way to do that, e.g., the larger message space?

Answer (score 1):

Fun question! We can, in fact, efficiently realise the maximum message space of size $(q-1)^t({n\atop t})$.

Let us begin with the case $q=2$. We want to generate a bit string of length $n$ and Hamming weight exactly $t$. There are $C:=({n\atop t})$ such strings and we would like to map an integer message from the interval $[0,C-1]$ to this set bijectively. Combinatorially speaking, the set of bit strings correspond to [combinations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combination) (specifically $t$-combinations of the integers 0 through $n-1$). We can bijectively rewrite our string as a strictly decreasing sequence of $t$ values $n-1\ge c_t>c_{t-1}>\ldots>c_1\ge 0$ by writing down the indices of the location of the 1s.

Now, an elegant theorem of mathematics that Knuth attributes to the 19th century mathematician Ernesto Pascal says that every number $N$ can be represented in the [combinatorial number system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combinatorial_number_system)
$$N=\left({c_t\atop t}\right)+\cdots+\left({c_1\atop 1}\right)$$
and this ordering steps through combinations is lexicographic order (for our purposes, the first $({n\atop t})$ entries list weight $t$ strings of length $n$). Therefore if we have an integer $N\in [0,C-1]$ we can use a greedy algorithm to recover the $N$th weight $t$ binary string given by the combinatorial number system. Here's some pseudo-code:

```
Initialise i:=n-1, j:=t, remainder=N
while i>=0
   if Binomial(i,j) > remainder
      set bit i of the string to 0
   else
      set bit i of the string to 1
         j--
         remainder -= Binomial(i,j)
   i--
```

The reverse map is straightforward.

For example, with $n=10$, $t=3$ there are 120 possible combinations, let us find the 17th (counting 0-up). We first find the smallest tetrahedral number not greater than 17; this is $({5\atop 3})=10$; we mark the 5th spot and have 7 left over. We now find the smallest triangular number not greater than 7; this is $({4\atop 2})=6$; we mark the 4th spot and have 1 left over. We now find the smallest number not greater than 1; this $({1\atop 1})=1$; we mark the 1st spot and have nothing left over. Our string is `0000110010`. If we receive the string we compute $({5\atop 3})+({4\atop 2})+({1\atop 1})=10+6+1=17$.

For more general alphabets, we can use the above process to generate the error locations and then choose from the $q-1$ possible error values for each location. Concretely let $M=C(q-1)^t$ be the size of our message space. Given a message $m\in[0,M-1]$ we let $N=[m/(q-1)^t]$ so that $N\in[0,C-1]$ and generate a list of locations as above. We then let $B=m\mod{(q-1)^t}$ and write $B$ as a $t$-digit number in base $(q-1)$ (allowing leading zeroes) and assign the values digit+1 to each location. Again the reverse map is straightforward.

For example suppose we have a decimal alphabet and consider strings of length 10 with 3 errors. There are 120*729=87480 possible messages; let us find the 12707th. We find $N=[12707/729]=17$ and so generate the same bits string as above. We find $B=12707\mod{729}=314$ which is 378 in base 9. Our message converts to the error string `0000480090`. Again if we receive this string, we pull out the non-zero digits in order and subtract one from each to give the base-9 number 378 so that $B=314$ likewise we know that $N=17$ from the error locations and can compute $m=729N+B=12707$.

Chapter 7.2.1.3 "Generating all Combinations" of Donald Knuth's definitive "The Art of Computer Programming" is an excellent, comprehensive (albeit distracting) account of other algorithms for generating combinations.