# Hash functions with constant number of 1's

Tags: hash, random-oracle-model

In the following paper: https://eprint.iacr.org/2018/056.pdf, the random oracle is defined as follows:
$ H: *\xrightarrow{} \{ \mathbf{v} | \mathbf{v} \in R_{q,[1]}, || \mathbf{v}||_{1}=\omega\}$

Where $R_{q,[1]}$ stands for those elements that belong to the ring $R_{q}=Z_{q}/<x^n+1>$ and have coefficients between [-1,1].

Are these random oracles secure? If so, which hash function could output a constant number of 1's without comprimissing the security?

Comment: I don't think that $||v||_1$ is cointing $1$s. It is rather $p-norm$ where $p$ is one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If they behave like random oracles, then they offer security commensurate with the size of the image space which is $2^\omega\binom n\omega$ (note that there are $\omega$ non-zero entries which can each be plus or minus one). Thus if the security is compromised by finding a collision in $H$ this should require $O(2^{\omega/2}\sqrt{\binom n\omega})$ evaluations of $H$ to find. For any given security level, it is possible to find appropriate values of $n$ and $\omega$ for which the required work is greater than the security level.

The easiest way to practically construct such an $H$ is to adapt a regular $h$-bit hash function that is believed to behave like a random oracle. Use this to generate a uniform value between 0 and $V:=2^\omega\binom n\omega$ (e.g. by treating the hash output as a $h$-bit integer; if this value is less than $2^h\mod V$, append a 1 to the input and iterate, else reduce the value modulo $V$). Now split the value $v$ into two values $c:=v/2^\omega$ and $b:=v\mod {2^\omega}$ (note that $b$ and $c$ will be independent and uniformly distributed modulo $2^\omega$ and $\binom n\omega$ respectively). Now use $c$ and the method of [this answer](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/97690/how-to-map-the-message-to-the-vector-of-weight-t-in-niederreiter-cryptosystem/97692#97692) to choose a set of $\omega$ coefficients that will be non-zero and use the bits of $b$ to select between the coefficients plus and minus 1.

Comment: Actually, an easier (if not as efficient) way to implement such an Oracle is to take the sequence $0, 1, 2, ..., n-1$, shuffle them using Fisher-Yates (using a good RNG seeded by a cryptographic hash of the string), and then take the resulting sequence, and convert any value $< \omega$ into a '1' bit and any value $\ge \omega$ into a 0 bit...

Comment: @poncho Easier still would be to use a XOF to generate uniform random values from $[0,n)$ until $\omega$ distinct values have been produced. The combinatorist in me still leans towards the precision of the combinatorial number system.