# Can a cryptographic hash function that outputs a c-membered subset of the n-membered set?

Tags: hash, collision-resistance, pseudo-random-function, password-hashing, random-oracle-model

Is it possible that there is a cryptographic hash function that outputs a c-membered subset of the n-membered set?
In other words, can the set of the binary representation of c-membered subsets of the n-membered set, be the range of a hash function?

The hash function will look like below (for 2-membered subset of the 4-membered set):

H: G --- {0011, 0010}

Comment: One possible solution is mapping the output of a cryptographic hash function to the c-members. if the output is even, then to 0010 if odd then 0011. It might be problematic if the c-membered set is not a regular... So, what is the actual use case?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, take any cryptographic hash function $f$ whose output space is greater than $m:=\binom{n}{c}$ which is the number of possible subsets. To map the value $x$, we reduce the output of $f(x)$ modulo $m$ (if we want uniformity, we rehash if $f(x)<f(x)\mod m$), to get a reduced value $y$ such that $0\le y<m$. We then represent $y$ is the [combinatorial number system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combinatorial_number_system) and use this representation to specify the $c$ elements of the subset.

A more detailed description of the combinatorial conversion can be found in [my answer to this question](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/97690/how-to-map-the-message-to-the-vector-of-weight-t-in-niederreiter-cryptosystem).

Comment: Absolutely, a professional answer. Thanks a lot Dr. @daniel-s .