# How to generate n unique numbers from the output of a hash function?

Tags: hash, pseudo-random-generator

What would be an easy way to use the hexadecimal output of a hash function (like md5) to generate `n` **unique** numbers from, say 0 to 15. Of course I could generate n numbers by using each digit of the digest, but I need those numbers to be **unique**.

Comment: What is the aim? What is the actual range? Do you really need to use hash functions? Discarding is the easiest....

Comment: @kelalaka The problem with the simple discard method is that it uses an undetermined amount of random bits. And, as [I've shown](https://github.com/owlstead/RNG-BC/blob/master/README.md),  it is **very** inefficient if the number is discarded. With an average of 1.7 bits of overhead at least the RNG-BC method that I've described has a chance of *usually* keeping within 128 bits produced by MD5.

Comment: Are there any requirements imposed on the resulting numbers? The simplest way is [MD5 + 0, MD5 + 1, ..., MD5 + n] and they will all be unique. Or do you mean 0..15 is the range of the resulting numbers? In that case, you can index into [0, 1, ..., 15] and use that as the first number and the remaining n as the rest.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes sure it is undetermined, however, the range is not specified, instead it was made so simple. Fisher-Yates shuffle and it's varianst's is the usual way, however, the OP mentioned hash so I've wanted to clarify. Eugene's solution is more precise.

Comment: The easiest way to get *n* unique numbers is *counting* (from 1 to *n*).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should use the [combinatorial number system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combinatorial_number_system#Finding_the_k-combination_for_a_given_number) to bijectively map an integer in the range 0 to $\binom{16}n-1$ an $n$-element subset of the first 16 numbers. I wrote a related answer on [mapping messages to error positions in the Niederreiter cryptography system](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/97690/how-to-map-the-message-to-the-vector-of-weight-t-in-niederreiter-cryptosystem/97692#97692).

Comment: Hmm, seems very much like the method that I'm proposing, not sure if it is entirely the same.

Comment: So we find the combinadics representation of an integer in the range 0 to ${16 \choose n} - 1$ for degree `n`?

Comment: @Starscream512 Yes, that's exactly it. Use the hash function to generate such an integer uniformly and then convert it to a subset. It's clearly information theory optimal.

Comment: Getting more and more sure that it is functionally the same as what is in my answer. Fisher-Yates uses it to index and shuffle so that lists other than ranges are supported, but I guess that's about the difference.

Comment: Is there a work for the quality of the randomness? I have not seen around, interestingly Wiki says it i used also used for the analysis of lottery games. If the lotteries not used in the real application then there is a something that they see but I've failed.

Comment: Your answer then leads to my next question about modulo bias in generating an integer using a hash function. I suppose if ${16 \choose n}$ wasn't too big, and I used a big hash like sha256, then the modulo bias would be negligible?

Comment: I'd certainly argue for SHA-256 in this case, it would get rid of any possible bias issues, however small. MD5 has a lot of problems, one is that it is severely broken especially w.r.t. collision resistance, which **may** very well play a role here, and the other important one is the output size, which is not enough to assure collision resistance in the first place.

Answer (score 4):

TL;DR: use the *[Fisher-Yates shuffle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle) based on a seed* of the range represented as a list; the hash value is the seed.

---

First of all, MD5 generates 16 bytes that are generally well distributed. It doesn't generate hexadecimals; those are just used to *represent* the bytes in a textual form.

You can generate values in a range using the Fisher-Yates shuffle. However, this requires you first to draw an number in the range `[0..n)`, then `[0..n - 1)` until `[0..2)`. Generally getting random numbers from bits is tricky because most algorithms use a non-deterministic number of bits.

In this case you can use a factorial of `n`, then choose a vector using that to compute the required number in a range.

So you'll get something like the following Python code, which implements the shuffle based on a 128 bit seed:

```
from decimal import Decimal, getcontext
from hashlib import md5
import math

# Setting the precision for decimal operations
getcontext().prec = 50

def fisher_yates_shuffle(n, seed):
    # Guard clause: Check the type and size of the seed
    if not isinstance(seed, int) or seed.bit_length() != 128:
        raise ValueError("Seed must be a 128-bit integer.")

    # Initialize the array from 0 to n-1
    arr = list(range(n))

    # Convert the seed to a decimal
    random_decimal = Decimal(seed) / Decimal(2**128)

    # Calculate the product x of all numbers in [0, 1, ..., n-1]
    x = math.factorial(n)
    
    # Pick a starting point within [0, x)
    current_vector = random_decimal * Decimal(x)

    for i in range(n - 1, 0, -1):
        # Generate a value for i-th index using current_vector
        i_value = int(current_vector % Decimal(i + 1))

        # Perform the shuffle step
        arr[i], arr[i_value] = arr[i_value], arr[i]

        # Update the current_vector for the next iteration
        current_vector //= Decimal(i + 1)

    return arr

# Generate a 128-bit random seed from MD5 hash of "Hello World"
seed_str = "Hello World"
md5_hash = md5(seed_str.encode('utf-8')).digest()
seed = int.from_bytes(md5_hash, byteorder='big')

# Number of elements in the array (max)
n = 16

# Perform the Fisher-Yates shuffle
result = fisher_yates_shuffle(n, seed)

print("Shuffled array:", result)
```

Written with the help of ChatGPT, but altered & logically validated.

Note that some bias is introduced, somewhere around $\frac{1}{2^{88}}$ for 16 values. Usually that's considered negligible, but it pays to be careful when it comes to cryptography.